# Maven jar without dependencies by default

Tags: maven, jar

Why does jar built with maven-jar not contain all dependencies libs **by default** (you need to *use jar-with-dependencies* option)

Comment: Because a jar does not contain the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the vast majority of JAR modules have the use case of being in the end modules of an application (WAR, EAR, executable JAR).
The use case of directly having a fat executable JAR is rather limited compared to that modularity use case
.

And think about it, when you have a slim JAR, you always have the ability to create another module that will assemble that JAR with another in order to create an application. If you directly generate a fat JAR, you will reduce the ease of way your module can be integrated to others.